# web site with Java EE and workflow

Tags: jakarta-ee, workflow

Could you please advice me a tutorial or book to do a web site using Java EE architecture and implement workfolw behind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this book to be very good:
https://www.packtpub.com/java-ee5-development-with-netbeans-6/book

It's quite tool specific being based on Netbeans and Glassfish but even if you're not planning on using these ultimately, I still find it useful to have concrete examples to work with. In general, Packt are great for technology specific guides rather than the big picture but sometimes the best way to get the big picture is to work through a specific example and get that working. You can generalise afterwards once you have the base case down.

Answer (score 1):

You should try JBoss jBPM which is JBPM 2.0 compilant and has a pretty good documentation and tooling (based on Eclipse platform).

http://www.jboss.org/jbpm/documentation